# array of string pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know that strings in C are basically an array of characters.

I was trying have an array of pointers, pointers which link to the strings

I basically wanted to print this out, without depending on '\n' to sort it

```
12345
abcde
67890
fghij
```

This is my code - >

```
char *array1 = "12345";
char *array2 = "abcde";
char *array3 = "67890";
char *array4 = "fghij";

char *array_2d[3];

array_2d[0] = &array1; 
array_2d[1] = &array2; 
array_2d[2] = &array3;
array_2d[3] = &array4;

int i,j;

for(i = 0; i<3 ; i++ ) {
    for(j = 0; j<3 ; j++) {
        printf("%c", array_2d[i][j]);
    }
}
```

i might be making mistakes, so any clues would be appreciated

Comment: Note that your array should be size 4 to hold all four strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

1. you declare `char *array_2d[3]` which means your have an array size of 3 with indexes 0 to 2 but you assign `array_2d[3] = &array4:`
2. your variables `array1` to `array4` are already `char *` so the correct assignment to elements in `array_2d` would be `array_2d[0] = array1` and so on

Answer (score 5):

> I know that strings in C are basically an array of characters.

A *string* is a *null-terminated array of characters*.

> `array_2d[0] = &array1;`

`&array1` has `char **` type (pointer to string), whereas you want a `char *` (ie. `array1`).

```
array_2d[0] = array1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char *array1 = "12345";
    char *array2 = "abcde";
    char *array3 = "67890";
    char *array4 = "fghij";

    char *array_2d[4];

    array_2d[0] = array1;
    array_2d[1] = array2;
    array_2d[2] = array3;
    array_2d[3] = array4;

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", array_2d[i][j]);
        }
        printf(@"\n");
    }

}
```