# creating a 2D array out of an array of string pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

This is an extension to my previous query - 
[array of string pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447283/array-of-string-pointers-in-c)

I have this working sample code in C

```
int main(void)
{
    char *array1 = "12345";
    char *array2 = "abcde";
    char *array3 = "67890";
    char *array4 = "fghij";

    char *array_2d[4];

    array_2d[0] = array1; 
    array_2d[1] = array2; 
    array_2d[2] = array3;
    array_2d[3] = array4;

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i<=3 ; i++ ) {
        for(j = 0; j<=4 ; j++) {
            printf("%c", array_2d[i][j]);

        }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

I would like to de-reference

```
*array1 to *array4
```

i.e.

```
array_2d[0] -> "12345" 
....
array_2d[3] -> "fghij"
```

and not

```
array_2d[0] -> array1 -> "12345"
....
array_2d[3] -> array4 -> "fghij"
```

Is this possible ? I would maybe like to increase array_2d to [8]
and say

```
array_2d[4] -> array1 -> "ABCDE"
....
array_2d[7] -> array4 -> "FGHIJ"
```

I hope this seems clear....

EDIT -

I think i got it. This is what i was trying to do.

```
char *array1 = "12345";
char *array2 = "abcde";
char *array3 = "67890";
char *array4 = "fghij";

char *array_2d[8];

array_2d[0] = array1; 
array_2d[1] = array2; 
array_2d[2] = array3;
array_2d[3] = array4;

array1 = "AAAAA";
array2 = "BBBBB";
array3 = "CCCCC";
array4 = "DDDDD";

array_2d[4] = array1; 
array_2d[5] = array2; 
array_2d[6] = array3;
array_2d[7] = array4;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  `array_2d` is not a 2D array at all - it's a 1D array of pointers.  What does your notation `array_2d[0] -> array1 -> "12345"` mean?

Comment: Your situation now is array_2d[0] -> "12345", not array_2d[0] -> array1 -> "12345". So you have achieved exactly what you want.

Comment: I would like that array_2d[0] copies "12345" from array1, so i can empty array1 and store(point) "ABCDE" , then array_2d[4] copies "ABCDE" from array1.

Comment: You can't modify the array that `array1` points to, because it's a literal. You can reassign `array1` to point to a different array, that doesn't affect `array_2d[0]`.

Comment: @KamenStoykov , so if i directly just re-assign say *array1 = "ABCDE" and then say array_2d[4] = array1. It should should work ?

Comment: array1 is a variable storing a memory address - the address of the first byte in your c-string. array_2d[0] stores that same memory address, because you assigned to it from the memory address in array1. If you want them to be independent, then `array_2d[0] = strdup(array1);`

Comment: @Sid5427 You can do `array1 = "ABCDE"`, not `*array1 = "ABCDE"`.

Comment: ah yes, sorry about that, copy pasted it.

Comment: In general - yes, but char *array = "ABCDE"; should be const char *, so you can't just reassign it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think this is what you're asking about.

```
int main(void)
{
    char *array1 = "12345";
    char *array2 = "abcde";
    char *array3 = "67890";
    char *array4 = "fghij";

    char *array_2d[8];

    array_2d[0] = array1; 
    array_2d[1] = array2; 
    array_2d[2] = array3;
    array_2d[3] = array4;

    array1 = "ABCDE";
    array2 = "GHIJK";
    array3 = "LMNOP";
    array4 = "QRSTU";

    array_2d[4] = array1;
    array_2d[5] = array2;
    array_2d[6] = array3;
    array_2d[7] = array4;

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i<=7 ; i++ ) {
        for(j = 0; j<=4 ; j++) {
            printf("%c", array_2d[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Reassigning `array1` doesn't affect what `array_2d[0]` points to. The original assignment just copies the pointer, it doesn't make them aliases for each other.

Comment: Yup exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, it is not completely clear to me what is being asked, but it is possible to make copies of the strings as follows (this is just one possible way):

```
char *array_2d[8];

array_2d[0] = strdup( array1 ); 
...
array_2d[4] = strdup( array_2d[1] ); 
strupr( array_2d[4] );
...
```

This will result in putting separately allocated strings in each location.  [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) makes a copy of string.  Note that you have to call free() (e.g., `free( array_2d[0] );`) to free that memory.

Another thing to note: The OP seems to indicate that you plan to modify the array (string) pointed to by `array1`.  You cannot change that memory (it is a string constant).  You can change what `array1` points to, though.